# Wrong python binary virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I recently installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on my mac to work on a Django Project.

My problem is that when I am in my virtualenv and  I enter python manage.py runserver, for some reason the python binary used is not the one inside my virtualenv. I have a mac book air with OS 10.8.3

When I enter name_of_virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver everything works fine.

When I run which python I get : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

How can I change that so that the default python is the good one ?

I did not specify any python version in my requirements.txt.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv (since you're using the wrapper, that would be `workon my_env_name`)?

Comment: Yes, I did activate it, I edited my question.

Comment: Run `which python` after activating venv and before running `runserver`, what do you see?

Comment: I get /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't activated the environment. You do that either by:

```
source ./bin/activate
```

or with virtualenvwrapper:

```
workon <theenvname>
```

Note that you don't need to do any of this. Running Django with

```
./bin/python manage.py runserver
```

Works just fine. You don't **have** to actually activate the virtualenv. Personally I never do.

Comment: This is strange because I have a line : workon <envname> in my .bashrc and my prompt indicates that the environment is active
When I re-enter workon <envname> then the result of which python changes point to my virtualenv

Comment: Strange indeed, but as mentioned, you don't have to activate anything.